# ImportRange Function to Ignore Empty Gaps between Sheet A and Sheet B

Tags: google-sheets

How can I combine 2 spreadsheets into one without any gaps? When I import range 2 sheets, there is a gap of ~1000 rows. To make sure there are no gaps between the 2 sheets, I usually create a query "Where Col1 is not null " but I am missing some info. :(

My spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSnbySwNPEvkkXqw6ItuBpZ_6-o58HPlVicIHWD0Y4I/edit#gid=381064131

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just being three columns:

```
=query({
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSnbySwNPEvkkXqw6ItuBpZ_6-o58HPlVicIHWD0Y4I/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A2:C");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSnbySwNPEvkkXqw6ItuBpZ_6-o58HPlVicIHWD0Y4I/edit#gid=0", "Sheet2!A2:C")}, "Select * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col2 is not null OR Col3 is not null")
```

A second possible scenario for avoiding empty rows, no matter how many columns you have is wrapping your range or query in LAMBDA, and use FILTER associated with BYROW and COUNTA. If there are no elements in any row, then the count will be 0 and it will be filtered out:

```
=LAMBDA(quer,FILTER(quer, BYROW (quer, LAMBDA (each,COUNTA(each)))))({
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSnbySwNPEvkkXqw6ItuBpZ_6-o58HPlVicIHWD0Y4I/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A2:C");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSnbySwNPEvkkXqw6ItuBpZ_6-o58HPlVicIHWD0Y4I/edit#gid=0", "Sheet2!A2:C")})
```

Both solutions return:

[image]